# how do i delete multiple rows table using angular js with php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Now this is my html code

```
                        <tr  ng-repeat="x in details| filter:maincode">
                        <td>{{x.maincode}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.subcode}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.trandate}}</td>


                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete Data  </button>
```

when i click delete button all data will not deleted in selected maincode this is my controller js code

```
                        $scope.deleteInfo = function(info){


                             var x = confirm("Are you sure to delete the selected data");
                            if(x){
                                                $http.post('databases/dele_setlemnt_data.php', {"maincode":info.maincode}).success(function(data){
                                                    if (data == true) {
                                                     alert("Data has been deleted Successfully");   
                                                    getInfo();
                                                    }


                                                });
                        }   
                        }
```

After the click delete button i saw console data not post and not taken php page that is my php page code

```
          <?php             
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

            $maincode= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->maincode);
            $query = "select * FROM trd_settle WHERE maincode= '{$maincode}' ";
                      echo $query;
            mysqli_query($con, $query);
            echo true;
```

i want to delete all data in one delete button click from the selected maincode..please tell me what is my mistakes now

Comment: Where is your tr ends?

Comment: You want to delete selected table rows?

Comment: I want to delete all rows  which select the maincode

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode)"
```

to

```
ng-click="deleteInfo(x)"
```

Comment: I have replace from ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode) to ng-click="deleteInfo(x) then  check in console delete function  will not  call

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode)">
```

Change this line as follows

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteInfo(x)">
```

And 'maincode' is column name, you should not pass that.

Here you are deleting row by row

If you want to delete selected maincode rows.

```
$scope.selectedIds = [];
$scope.deleteInfo = function () {
  angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
    if(value.maincode) {
      $scope.selectedIds(value.id);
    }
  }
}
```

You send to API layer ids and based on that delete DB rows.

Comment: I have replace from ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode) to ng-click="deleteInfo(x) then  check in console delete function  will not  call

Comment: deleteInfo should call, no changes we did and before its calling!!

Comment: where my mistakes..?

Comment: deleteinfo are not calling after the changed from ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode) to ng-click="deleteInfo(x)

Comment: Javascript is excellent language to accept deleteInfo() too. It will work deleteInfo(x), deleteInfo(maincode), deleteInfo(x, maincode) too

Comment: deleteinfo() function are calling when write  ng-click="deleteInfo(maincode)" not working deleteInfo(x),deleteInfo(x,maincode) what can i do..?

Comment: how can fit that code $scope.selectedIds = [];
$scope.deleteInfo = function () {
  angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
    if(value.maincode) {
      $scope.selectedIds(value.id);
    }
  }
} because i run script in php

Comment: when in print_r($data) console will be blank now stdClass Object
(
)
select * FROM trd_settle WHERE maincode= '' 1

Comment: mincode value not pass deleinfo function to php page

Comment: If we use deleteInfo(x), x contains maincode value also.

Answer (score 0):

hi check this to understand the difference

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
 $scope.details =[];
 $scope.details.push({id:1,maincode:"maincode 1",subcode:"subcode 1"});
 $scope.details.push({id:2,maincode:"maincode 2",subcode:"subcode 2"});
 $scope.details.push({id:3,maincode:"maincode 3",subcode:"subcode 3"});
 $scope.details.push({id:4,maincode:"maincode 4",subcode:"subcode 4"});
 $scope.details.push({id:5,maincode:"maincode 5",subcode:"subcode 5"});
 $scope.details.push({id:6,maincode:"maincode 6",subcode:"subcode 6"});
 
$scope.deleteInfo = function(maincode,info,idx){
console.log("maincode",maincode);

//get obj data
console.log("info",info);

//show the index of list
console.log("index",idx);

//remove from list
$scope.details.splice(idx, 1);


};
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div  ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<table>
<tr  ng-repeat="x in details">
<td>{{$index}}</td>
<td>{{x.maincode}}</td>
<td>{{x.subcode}}</td>
<td> <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteInfo(x.maincode,x,$index)">Delete</td>

</tr>
<table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx for this code..but I want to delete bulk/multiple rows data not single to single data.i have only one delete button then click button delete all rows to selected maincode..

Comment: this can do in php and send in php only the maincode after delete in php you have to set the results in detais data again

Comment: I have done single row to delete but I want to delete all rows in single button is that my problem now..if you want to see my code I show you.

Comment: if the data in field maincode is the same in each row so the sql can delete all rows with 1 batch

Comment: so you are we  add index in my table row..?

Comment: sorry for my late yes is better to add index to group your records if have to make batch sql for my opinion